# After an upgrade to 18.04.2 LTS system freezes with only mouse movement when trying to access files on my second physical disk

Tags: 18.04, upgrade

After an upgrade to 18.04.2 LTS system freezes with only mouse movement when trying to access files on my second physical disk.

[image: desktop system information]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. The second disk was partitioned into a EXT4 partition and a NTFS partition. Whenever I tried to access the NTSF partition, the system froze with only mouse movements. I ran 16.04 from my CD and backed up all my data off of the second drive and reformatted it with one EXT4 partition. System works ok now. Old Partition Information